# renaming object with value from string array

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to use a value from an array of strings in place of the name of my object "midgaard"
I tried both to change it to scene[0] and scene[0]. but nothing works.
I dont understand the logic behind clearly.
what can i do to replace midgard with a value from the array?

```
const whatDay = ["mon", "tue", "wed"];

const scene = ["midgard"];

function playingWhen(whatDay, scene) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < whatDay.length; x++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < scene[0][whatDay[x]].length; i++) { //<-----
      console.log(i, midgard[whatDay[x]][i].act);
      arr.push({ [whatDay[x]]: midgard[whatDay[x]][i].act });
    }
  }
  console.log(arr);
}

playingWhen(whatDay);

const midgard = {
  mon: [
    { start: "00:00", end: "02:00", act: "Barrows Group", cancelled: true },
    { start: "02:00", end: "04:00", act: "break" },
  ],
  tue: [
    { start: "00:00", end: "02:00", act: "Bartell - Cummerata", cancelled: true },
    { start: "02:00", end: "04:00", act: "break" },
  ],
  wed: [
    { start: "00:00", end: "02:00", act: "A Perfect Circle" },
    { start: "02:00", end: "04:00", act: "break" },
  ],
};
```

Comment: you want to access midgard through scene[0]? you cann't do it like that, midgard is not inside any other object

Comment: yea that was the idea, how do i access it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make an object which contains all the scenes, something like that:

```
const scenes = {
midgard :{
  mon: [
    { start: "00:00", end: "02:00", act: "Barrows Group", cancelled: true },
    { start: "02:00", end: "04:00", act: "break" },
  ],
  tue: [
    { start: "00:00", end: "02:00", act: "Bartell - Cummerata", cancelled: true },
    { start: "02:00", end: "04:00", act: "break" },
  ],
  wed: [
    { start: "00:00", end: "02:00", act: "A Perfect Circle" },
    { start: "02:00", end: "04:00", act: "break" },
  ],
}

}
```

and then you can access it like that:

```
scenes[scene[0]]
```

it will make your code harder to read, try using Object Destructuring

Comment: how can I improve my answer? I did mention it will make the code less readable, and as I understood, midgard is realy only a one of the scenes

Comment: yes idea is to introduce more scenes, , but yes it looks very crazy how would i destructure it? thanks alot for answering!

Comment: you can read about it here, the idea is just to keep it shorter -https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment